# JavaScript and jQuery error with function parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters

Hi  I  have problem with JavaScript function with parameters.

I created function:

```
function setBundleExpiration(parameters) {
    alert(parameters);
};
```

and in C# code behind I add some parameters:

```
Link.OnClientClick = "setBundleExpiration(" + Test.AuthorizedUserID + ");";
```

this is guid parameter and this does not work. I have problem in JS like:

```
 SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'
```

but if I use id as parameter id with 3 char length then is okay.

and here is place in html where error message shows:

```
 <a onclick="setBundleExpiration(3110cb24da214b4cbc00eb5cd5e020fc);"
```

link is correctly closed!

Can somebody show me how to pass few parameter to js or query function without errors ? Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Link.OnClientClick = "setBundleExpiration('" + Test.AuthorizedUserID + "');";
```

Try adding `'` around your GUID. The JS thinks your GUID is a variable. You need to pass it as a string.